# C# Assigning json output to an array

Tags: c#, json

Am getting an output from a http request like this

```
 LoginResponse loginresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(result);
```

In my class LoginResponse

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a data class

```
    public class Data
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public Array permissions { get; set; }
}
```

The response from http looks like follows

```
{
  "status":true,
  "data": {
    "permissions": [
        "permission1",
        "permission2",
        "permission3"
      ],
      "access_token": "kerJVXOLe8yBNLWVx3quCliLuIYkH1JJ",
        ......
}
```

The problem comes in when i assign permission as an array in the class data such that am getting an error

```
Coould not create an instance of System.Array
```

How should i resolve this as permissions are an arrayof strings
so that i can easily access then in a forloop as

```
loginresponse.data.permissions
```

Comment: It should be `public string[] permissions { get; set; }` or `public List<string> permissions { get; set; }`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you use `Array` instead of `string[]`?

Comment: Am new to c# didnt have an idea that you can use String[], am used to typescript(javascript) arrays

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya answer is right on the money. That will make it work.

Comment: Thanks all it works

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, `Array` type

> Provides methods for creating, manipulating, searching, and sorting arrays, thereby serving as the base class for all arrays in the common language runtime.

In this case you should use `string[]`:

```
public string[] permissions { get; set; }
```

or `List<string>`:

```
public List<string> permissions { get; set; }
```